# How can I make CurrentValue for font characteristics pick up the font of the output not the input cell?

Tags: programming, output-formatting, fonts

The command `CurrentValue` ([documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html)) allows you to access various properties of fonts, such as x-height, line height, and various measures of width such as n-width and m-width. This has obvious applications in determining appropriate sizes of objects so that the text contained within them fits.

However it is not obvious how to pick up the characteristics of the font of styled output. For example, the following uses the width of the font in the input cell, not the selected style in the code (example adopted from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1679/8)).

```
 Framed @ Graphics[Text[
  Style["how quickly daft jumping zebras vex", 
   FontFamily -> "Verdana", FontSize -> 20]], 
 ImageSize -> CurrentValue["FontNWidth"]*35]
```

[image]

If I select the whole input cell (by its bracket, not just the text) and change the font, it works better, although of course `"FontNWidth"` is not a perfect indicator of actual width of characters:

[image]

How can I concisely get the `CurrentValue` dimensions from an arbitrarily chosen font?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```
{Framed@Graphics[
   Text[Style[DynamicWrapper["how quickly daft jumping zebras vex",
       p = CurrentValue["FontNWidth"]], FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
     FontSize -> 20]], ImageSize -> Dynamic[p]*35], Dynamic[p]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This code demonstrates that the font chosen for the styled output is definitely being picked up by `CurrentValue`.

```
Manipulate[{Framed@
   Graphics[
    Text[Style[
      DynamicWrapper["how quickly daft jumping zebras vex", 
       p = CurrentValue["FontNWidth"]], FontFamily -> fontfam, 
      FontSize -> i]], ImageSize -> Dynamic[p]*42], Dynamic[p]}, {i, 
  10, 40}, {fontfam, {"Verdana", "Arial", "TimesNewRoman", "Tahoma"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Neat!
 Someday, I should start looking into `Dynamic*`...

Comment: I don;t see a need for a dynamic wrapper @Heike. As per my answer you can just make the current value Dynamic directly.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch That doesn't work on my system. If I run your edited code I always get a value of 7.02114 for `CurrentValue["FontNWidth"]` independent of `FontSize` and `FontFamily`.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch but it seems to be the difference that makes it work. Consider `Manipulate[{Framed@
   Graphics[
    Text[Style[
      DynamicWrapper["how quickly daft jumping zebras vex", 
       p = CurrentValue["FontNWidth"]], FontFamily -> "Verdana", 
      FontSize -> i]], ImageSize -> Dynamic[p]*46], Dynamic[p]}, {i, 
  10, 40}]`

Comment: @Heike what are you using? I wrote my answer with 8.0.4 on OS X 10.6.8 and it works fine -- as per screen grabs.

Comment: @Verbeia As per my answer to Heike this must be a system specific problem because on Mac Snow Leopard my answer delivers exactly what your `Manipulate` does but much simpler -- as per screen grabs.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm using Mathematica 8.0.4 on OS X Lion 10.7.3.

Comment: Actually when I commented above about not needing `DynamicWrapper` I hadn't tried your code. On my Mac your code doesn't work. The value of p is constant regardless of what you change the font size to, and consequently the image size never changes.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Are you changing the font of the text in the box (using the FontSize and FontFamily options) or of the Cell itself? If I look at the last two screen grabs in your post, the font of the text in the boxes look the same to me, but the brackets and number are in a different style.

Comment: @Heike ok we're on the same page. I have misinterpreted Verbeias question.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'm glad it got sorted out