# Confusing font information from CurrentValue

Tags: front-end, dynamic, fonts, interactive

I'm trying to programmatically get the width of a character in Mathematica's default fixed-width font, Courier. I believe [`CurrentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html) holds the answer but I'm having trouble understanding correct usage.

Four examples:

```
In[1]:= CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, FontFamily]
Out[1]= "Times"
```

Example 1: Expected Courier, since input is typed in Courier.

```
In[2]:= s = Style["Confusion", FontFamily -> "Times"]; CurrentValue[s, FontFamily]
Out[2]= "Courier"
```

Example 2: Expected Times, since I specifically chose that font family for `s`.

```
In[3]:= CurrentValue[s, "FontMWidth"] / CurrentValue[s, "FontNWidth"]
Out[3]= 2.
```

Example 3: Expected exactly 1, since since all letters should be equally wide in Courier.

```
In[4]:= CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "FontMWidth"] / CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, "FontNWidth"]
Out[4]= 2.
```

Example 4: Expected about 1.2, based on a quick measurement of the width ratio of Times' M to N.

A [prior question about fonts and CurrentValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1684/how-can-i-make-currentvalue-for-font-characteristics-pick-up-the-font-of-the-out) has an example of using [`DynamicWrapper`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicWrapper.html) to get information out of dynamic objects, but I'm still curious how to use `CurrentValue` correctly in non-dynamic settings, and why the ratio of `FontMWidth/FontNWidth` is always 2.

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8.5 and Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Comment: discussion here may be relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/grid-layout-problems-different-sizes-when-rendering-on-mac-and-windows

Comment: @Mike Thanks, right on.

Answer (score 5):

After additional research, I believe I can (mostly) explain all four examples.

Example 1: `CurrentValue` is returning the default font for the front end, not the font you're typing in. It's the same as looking at Options Inspector→Formatting→Font→FontFamily, or evaluating:

```
Options[$FrontEnd, FontFamily]
(*
  {FontFamily -> "Times"}
*)
```

Example 2: `CurrentValue` is returning the font of the input cell. You can change the cell font and get different results.

[image: CurrentValue output from cell font change]

`CurrentValue` is likely falling back on a default response for cases where it's given an [object](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/BasicObjects.html) it doesn't have specific behavior for, although this is conjecture*. Broadly speaking, `CurrentValue` is for interacting with the front end, so it's little surprise that `s`, or any such symbol, is not among by `CurrentValue`'s repertoire. The objects `CurrentValue` can report on are in the [reference documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CurrentValue.html#6089) and the M.SE question "[Items known by CurrentValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/items-known-by-currentvalue)."

<sup>* Tracing CurrentValue reveals a MathLink call to the front end, at which point my investigative skills diminish.</sup>

Examples 3 & 4: These appear to be related to a [genuine bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17795/grid-layout-problems-different-sizes-when-rendering-on-mac-and-windows) with calculating character width on OS X.