# Extracting box coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dimensions of the results of Text[] within Graphics[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/dimensions-of-the-results-of-text-within-graphics)

In writing the following code, I had to figure out what values to give d by trial and error.  Is there a way to extract the coordinates of a box directly?

```
sty[list_] := 
 Framed[Style[list, Medium, 12, FontFamily -> "Arial", 
   Background -> White]]

listy[list_, place_] := Text[sty[Grid[list]], place]

Manipulate[
 Graphics[
  If[d < .675,
   {
    listy[{{2, 12, 7}}, {d, 0}],
    listy[{{5, 7}}, {2 - d, 0}]
    },
   {
    listy[{{2, 12, 7, 5, 7}}, {.93, 0}]
    }
   ],
  PlotRange -> {{-.5, 2.5}, {-.2, .2}},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
  ],
 {{d, .6, ""}, .6, .77},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 Paneled -> False, SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

Comment: By figuring out by trial and error is that what the `Manipulate` is for? It isn't clear exactly what you want -- in this example what value of d would you have like to have determined directly (in some way)? Is it the point that the two frames merge?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of one of these; please take a look:  [Dimensions of the results of `Text[]` within `Graphics[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/dimensions-of-the-results-of-text-within-graphics) and [Computing the bounding boxes for Text objects](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/computing-the-bounding-boxes-for-text-objects)