# Graphics from text left justified

Tags: graphics, text, style

I need to create a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object from text but it needs to be left justified. I can do this for a single text string:

```
Graphics[
 Text[
  Style["programa_de_estabilidade_e_crescimento", 16]
  , {1, 0}
  , {1.6, 0}
  ]
 , ImageSize -> {400, 20}
 ]
```

which results in:

[image]

But I need to do it automatically for different text sizes. E.g., using the same offset with the text string "programa" it results in:

[image]

So, is there a way to automatically adjust the offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the correct specification for the offset of `Text` (i.e. offset *after* coords), and specifying `PlotRange`, we can achieve consistent results:

```
textImg[txt_] := Graphics[
 Text[Style[txt, 16], {1.6, 0}, {-1, -1}], 
 ImageSize -> {400, 20},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, All}
]

textImg["programa"]

textImg["programa_de_estabilidade_e_crescimento"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You might also be able to use [`Alignment`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alignment.html) on an enclosing object to achieve the result without specifying `PlotRange`.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it didn't work. I'm having a blank image for both cases.

Comment: What version/OS are you using? For me, the above code works fine on a fresh kernel in MMA 11.1, Win 10

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 11.1.1.0 with macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Did you try in an empty notebook with a fresh kernel? And can anyone else test the code on OS X/macOS?

Comment: I was able to made it work but with a different parameterisation. Thanks!

Comment: do you you how can I now measure the size of the image text part only?

Comment: Does [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/dimensions-of-the-results-of-text-within-graphics) work for you?

Comment: Thanks! `ImageDimensions[ImageCrop[textImg["text"]]]` from the second answer worked very well!

Answer (score 0):

From @Mathe172 I got the following correct result (working in with MMA 11.1.1 macOS Sierra 10.12.6):

```
textImg[txt_] := Graphics[
 Text[Style[txt, 16], {-400, 0}, {-1, -1}], 
 ImageSize -> {400, 20},
 PlotRange -> {{-400, 5}, {0,20}},Frame->False
]
```