# How can I get Mathematica to not mis-align plot labels when exporting to pdf without rasterizing the text?

Tags: plotting, export, labeling, pdf-format

I have this code:

```
p = ListPlot[Table[Table[{x, m x}, {x, 0, 20000, 100}],
                   {m, 0.05/20000, 7/20000, (7 - 0.05)/20000/20}], 
             PlotLabels -> {"a", "asdfdfasfasdfasd", a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, 
                            "adfsfasda", "aasdfadfsfasdafsdfasd"}, 
             PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 500]
rp = Rasterize[p]
Export["/tmp/foo2-p.pdf", p]
Export["/tmp/foo2-rp.pdf", rp]
Export["/tmp/foo2-p.png", p]
Export["/tmp/foo2-rp.png", rp]
```

I get the following images:

*foo2-p.pdf*:

[image: foo2-p.pdf]

*foo2-rp.pdf*:

[image: foo2-rp.pdf]

*foo2-p.png*:

[image: foo2-p.png]

*foo2-rp.png*:

[image: foo2-rp.png]

If I rasterize first, or if I export to png, then the long names are horizontally aligned with the other names.  However, if I export directly to pdf, then the names are horribly misaligned.  How do I fix this issue without rasterizing the labels?  And why is Mathematica doing this?  (If it's relevant, I'm using Mathematica 11.2.0.0 on Linux x86_64.)

---

I've noticed that, using ImageMagick to convert the pdfs to pngs to upload them, the plot labels seem to be centered in boxes that are correctly aligned.  So I suspect that one way of fixing this could be somehow tricking Mathematica into thinking that the shorter text is longer than it (a la LaTeX's `\smash`, `\rlap`, `\llap`, `\phantom`, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm coming the the conclusion that pdf export is buggy in computing bounding boxes.  I discovered I can fix the offset by adding:

```
/. Text[v_, Offset[{dx_, dy_}, {x_, y_}], {0, 0}] :>
  Text[v, Offset[{14, 0}, {x, y}], {Left, Center}]
```

(14 is a magic number that comes from inspecting the input form of graphics and looking that the difference between the size of the image as given by [Dimensions of the results of Text[] within Graphics[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1679/dimensions-of-the-results-of-text-within-graphics) and the specified `dx` offset)

So this code seems to work:

```
p = ListPlot[Table[Table[{x, m x}, {x, 0, 20000, 100}],
                   {m, 0.05/20000, 7/20000, (7 - 0.05)/20000/20}], 
             PlotLabels -> {"a", "asdfdfasfasdfasd", a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, 
                            "adfsfasda", "aasdfadfsfasdafsdfasd"}, 
             PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 500] /. 
    Text[v_, Offset[{dx_, dy_}, {x_, y_}], {0, 0}] :>
      Text[v, Offset[{14, 0}, {x, y}], {Left, Center}]
```

**Addendum**: From https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163490/12258, another option which seems to help but not fully solve the problem (see also [How does pdf export handle text alignment?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163564/how-does-pdf-export-handle-text-alignment)) is to include an explicit `FontSize`:

```
p = ListPlot[Table[Table[{x, m x}, {x, 0, 20000, 100}],
                   {m, 0.05/20000, 7/20000, (7 - 0.05)/20000/20}], 
             PlotLabels -> Map[Style[#1, 10]&,
                           {"a", "asdfdfasfasdfasd", a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, 
                            "adfsfasda", "aasdfadfsfasdafsdfasd"}], 
             PlotRange -> {Full, {0, 2}}, ImageSize -> 500]
```